# Explain to a Linux user how do BSD/OSX drivers work

Tags: osx, drivers

Linux drivers come in a form of kernel modules (`*.ko` files), which can be given parameters when loaded into the kernel and usually live in `/lib/modules/<kernel version>`.

What's the similar arrangement for BSD/OSX? For example, I've just installed MacFUSE and have hard time understanding what exactly did the installer put into my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about other BSD, but OSX have kernel extensions (known as `kext`).

Kexts live in `/System/Library/Extensions/`. Each of them is a folder, containing device description and instruction (those that makes a driver). Things in a kext need suitable file permissions (generally belong to user `0:0` with mask `755`) for it to work.

After a kext is in place, the OS will automatically load it on reboot (although sometimes instantly). Occasionally you need to clear the kext cache (`rm -r /System/Library/Extensions/Caches/`) before the new kext will work correctly.

Comment: and the nice thing about kexts is that, certain compatibility caveats aside, a kext can work across minor kernel updates and often even major ones. Mac OS X APIs are more "stable" and defined.

Comment: And the awesome thing about Linux kernel modules is that they can be compiled so they won't load on kernels where the functions/data descriptions don't match, so they work for a largeish stretch of kernel versions. Sadly, almost nobody uses this, as all modules that might be required are part of the kernel package... plus they can be loaded/unloaded automatically (or by hand).